# In Django, why is user.is_authenticated a method and not a member variable like is_staff

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I've lost some time with a bug in my app due to user authentication. I think that it's a bit confusing but maybe someone can explain the reason and it will appear to me very logical.

The `user.is_staff` is a member variable while `user.is_authenticated` is a method. However `is_authenticated` only returns True or False depending if the class is `User` or `AnonymousUser` (see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/)

Is there a reason for that? Why `user.is_authenticated` is a method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've been bit by this a couple of times. The name certainly *sounds* like a boolean, and it is either True or False, and it doesn't change unless you change your login status. The fact that it isn't a DB field shouldn't prevent it from being a per-instance attribute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `is_staff` is a database field and `is_authenticated` is not (since that would be strange). Maybe `is_authenticated` could be turned into a property, but django devs must have decided, that making it a function would be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

is_authenticated() just checks that the user has provided a valid username and password.
It would not allow to login user as guest user (If i am not wrong).

Comment: Nope, is_authenticated is just False for anonymous and True and authenticated user. At least in the trunk ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`is_authenticated()` is function which check weather User current object is populated or not.

It is not necessary to store the whether the object is populated or not in database because,

If it is correctly populated then only that particular object data is stored in database.

So, that `is_authenticated()` is method not a field
comming to the user.is_staff is filed which is used  to represent the particular user data is comes under staff ex:- super_user . inorder to differentiate user we need to store in data base